# Is there a way to add a PHP SimpleXMLElement to another SimpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, simplexml

The "addChild" method of SimpleXMLElement seems like it should be the right choice, but it apparently only takes strings representing the tagname of the new child.

There's the object-ish notation for referencing nodes of the tree and setting them, e.g. $simpleXMLNode->child = value, but that only seems to work for simple text/numeric values. If I try the following:

```
$s = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$t = new SimpleXMLElement('<child/>');
$s->a = $t;
echo $s->asXML()
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><a></a></root>
```

when I was hoping for:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><a><child/></a></root>
```

I thought of converting $t to a string and then adding it (after stripping out the XML declaration):

```
$s->a = substr($t->asXML(),22)
```

But this yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><a>&lt;child/&gt;</a></root>
```

Again, not what I was hoping for.

Is there a typical way to accomplish this kind of thing with SimpleXML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SimpleXML - AddChild with another SimpleXMLElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778865/php-simplexml-addchild-with-another-simplexmlelement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey unknown. You have to use the DOMElement interface to your SimpleXML objects to achieve this.

```
<?php

$s = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$t = new DOMElement('child');

$dom = dom_import_simplexml($s);
$dom->appendChild($t);

echo $s->asXML();
// <root><child/></root>
```

If you need more specific details, let me know. There are several examples in the documentation and comments for the dom_import_simplexml() method too: http://php.net/dom_import_simplexml

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help but you could also extend SimpleXML to work as you expect. Here is a project I worked on for [bLibrary Xml](http://code.google.com/p/blibrary/source/browse/trunk/classes/bXml.class.inc) class. You can look at it to tailor SimpleXml to work as you expect it.