# Adding a block of XML as child of a SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, addition, simpledom

I have this SimpleXMLElement object with a XML setup similar to the following...

```
$xml = <<<EOX
<books>
    <book>
        <name>ABCD</name>
    </book>
</books>
EOX;

$sx = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml );
```

Now I have a class named Book that contains info. about each book. The same class can also spit out the book info. in XML format akin the the above (the nested  block).. example,

```
$book = new Book( 'EFGH' );
$book->genXML();

... will generate
<book>
    <name>EFGH</name>
</book>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out a way by which I can use this generated XML block and append as a child of  so that now it looks like... for example..

```
// Non-existent member method. For illustration purposes only.
$sx->addXMLChild( $book->genXML() );    

...XML tree now looks like:
<books>
    <book>
        <name>ABCD</name>
    </book>
    <book>
        <name>EFGH</name>
    </book>
</books>
```

From what documentation I have read on SimpleXMLElement, **addChild()** won't get this done for you as it doesn't support XML data as tag value.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to add a PHP SimpleXMLElement to another SimpleXMLElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157104/367456)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions. First, you do it with the help of libxml / DOMDocument / SimpleXML: you have to import your `$sx` object to [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), create a `DOMDocumentFragment` and use [`DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php):

```
$doc = dom_import_simplexml($sx)->ownerDocument;

$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();     
$fragment->appendXML($book->genXML());
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);

// your original $sx is now already modified.
```

See the [Online Demo](http://eval.in/17715).

You can also extend from *SimpleXMLElement* and add a method that is providing this. Using this specialized object then would allow you to create the following easily:

```
$sx = new MySimpleXMLElement($xml);

$sx->addXML($book->genXML());
```

Another solution is to use an XML library that already has this feature built-in like *SimpleDOM*. You grab [SimpleDOM](http://code.google.com/p/simpledom/) and you use insertXML(), which works like the addXMLChild() method you were describing.

```
include 'SimpleDOM.php';

$books = simpledom_load_string(
    '<books>
        <book>
            <name>ABCD</name>
        </book>
    </books>'
);

$books->insertXML(
    '<book>
        <name>EFGH</name>
    </book>'
);
```

Comment: I'd go for the 1st method as it doesn't involve any external libraries. Played around with the code a bit and managed to figure out the exact code sequence. Thanks. That helped bigtime :)

Comment: Please contribute with the exact code sequence if you still have it...!

Comment: Hi kids, I added a code-example that shows how this works including an online demo. I dunno why this was not made available in the past three and a half years as this Q&A shows a basic and useful concept. You all might have had super secret code ;) - And yes, nowadays *SimpleDOM* is totally superfluous in my eyes.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();       
$doc->loadXML("<root/>");       

$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();     
$fragment->appendXML("<foo>text</foo><bar>text2</bar>");
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

This modifies the XML document by adding an XML fragment. [Online Demo](http://eval.in/17709).

Comment: Your code is fine and working: http://eval.in/17709 - Just remove the part about saving for the moment, you just have an XML modifying, unrelated problem of saving to disk which you should place in a different question.

Comment: @hakre saveXML returns a string, it doesn't actually save it to disk.