# PHP simplexml_load_string() - add child object to an object in a loop

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

So here is my code:

```
foreach($this->simpleXMLobject->path->toRecord->myRecord as $record)
{
    $childXML = new \CurlClass\GetXML($record->link, $this->timeout);
    $result = $childXML->get();
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    if($xml !== FALSE)
    {
        $record->newChild = $xml->newChaldData;
    }

}
```

As you can see i need to add Object to every `$this->simpleXMLobject->path->toRecord->myRecord` record.

And its not working!

In a `print_r()` of the final result i'm getting this:

```
[n] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [firstname] => ANGELA
        [lastname] => LEE
        [dob] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [id] => 67404998
        [newChild] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [0] => 



            )

    )
```

I know that i have the XML in a `$result`.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The XMLs:

```
<xml>
<result>
    <stats/>
    <somadata/>
    <somadata/>
    <somadata/>
    <crimeData>
        <person>
            <fName>Eric</fName>
            <lName>Eric</lName>
            <caseDetailed>data1</caseDetailes>
        </person>
        ...
        <person>
            <fName>Eric</fName>
            <lName>Eric</lName>
            <caseDetailes>https://urltocasedetailes.com/blha/nlha</caseDetailes>
        </person>
    </crimeData>
</result>
```

`https://urltocasedetailes.com/blha/nlha` returns this kind of data:

```
<xml>
<result>
    <stats/>
    <detailesPart1>
        <data1>Eric</data1>
        <data2>Eric</data2>
    </detailesPart1>
    <detailesPart2>
        <data1>Eric</data1>
        <data2>Eric</data2>
    </person>
    </crimeData>
</result>
```

The idea is to get data from 'https://urltocasedetailes.com/blha/nlha' as xml object and add to the original xml `<person>` records

**UPDATE**

If i replace this:

```
if($xml !== FALSE)
{
    $record->newChild = $xml->newChaldData;
}
```

With this:

```
if($xml !== FALSE)
{
    $record->newChild = $xml->newChaldData->child1;
}
```

It works! But that's not really what i need.

Comment: Have you looked at the [SimpleXMLElement::addChild](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) function?

Comment: tried it. same result.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question, you'll have to show an example of the XML you're working with and what you want to do with it.

Comment: Your code seems to have an issue, the function you are looking for is: newChildData not newChaldData as show in your snippet.

Comment: @ReidJohnson thats a typo. it's not a real vars.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro you can see the simpleXMLobject structure from  the code. XML is, obviously, the same.

Comment: @rinchik You'll have to do better than that, paste the result of **echo $record->asXML()** and **echo $xml->asXML()**.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro sorry i can't. really. XML contains private sensitive info. unfortunately i dont have the scheme. Will try to draw a mockup.

Comment: SimpleXML does not support to add another SimpleXMLelement as a new children out of the box. If you try that you should also see an error message because PHP tells you. If you search for that error message you should find existing Q&A like [Is there a way to add a PHP SimpleXMLElement to another SimpleXMLElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157104/367456) or [Adding a block of XML as child of a SimpleXMLElement object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1824568/367456) that have this solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take your mockup XMLs and try to exemplify how to add specific data to the original XML, hope this will help you:

```
<?php
$originalXML = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <crimeData>
        <person>
            <fName>Eric</fName>
            <lName>Eric</lName>
            <caseDetailes>https://urltocasedetailes.com/blha/nlha</caseDetailes>
        </person>
    </crimeData>
</result>
XML;

$childXML = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <crimeData>
        <person>
            <detailesPart1>
                <data1>Eric</data1>
                <data2>Eric</data2>
            </detailesPart1>
            <detailesPart2>
                <data1>Eric</data1>
                <data2>Eric</data2>
            </detailesPart2>
        </person>
    </crimeData>
</result>
XML;

$sxe     = new SimpleXMLElement($originalXML);
$persons = $sxe->xpath('//person');

foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $url = (string) $person->caseDetailes;

    // Retrieve the XML from the external location from caseDetailes
    // $childSxe = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true);

    // Using this just for the example purpose
    $childSxe = new SimpleXMLElement($childXML);

    // Retrieve detailesPart2 from your external XML
    $detailes = $childSxe->xpath('//detailesPart2');

    // Add detailesPart2/data1 to the person record
    foreach ($detailes as $detaile) {
        $person->addChild($detaile->data1->getName(), (string) $detaile->data1);
    }
}

echo $sxe->asXML();
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
    <crimeData>
        <person>
            <fName>Eric</fName>
            <lName>Eric</lName>
            <caseDetailes>https://urltocasedetailes.com/blha/nlha</caseDetailes>
            <data1>Eric</data1>
        </person>
    </crimeData>
</result>
```