# How to merge xml objects?

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

How can I combine two or more simpleXML objects?

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_file($file1);
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($file2);
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Please show examples of input and output.

Comment: like when you merge two arrays... But in this case they would be simplexml objects :D

Comment: What do you mean by "merge two arrays"?

Comment: like array(a,x,z) + array(a, b,d,o) = array(a,b,o,x,z)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SimpleXML: append one tree to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418019/simplexml-append-one-tree-to-another)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - SimpleXML - AddChild with another SimpleXMLElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778865/php-simplexml-addchild-with-another-simplexmlelement)

Answer (score 1):

You can typecast the XML into an array, merge ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) it, then typecast back to an object. Like so:

```
$xml = (object)array_merge((array)$xml1, (array)$xml2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new class and add those objects to the class to get a combined object.

```
class myXML {
  function add($xmlobj) {
    foreach ($xmlobj->children() as $key=>$obj) {
        $this->$key = $obj;
    }
  }
}

$xob1 = simplexml_load_file($file1);
$xob2 = simplexml_load_file($file2);
$xob3 = new myXML();
$xob3->add($xob1);
$xob3->add($xob2);
```