# Write raw xml in a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php

I have a `SimpleXMLElement` made, and I want to write my own XML inside it, whenever I write the XML it returns with `&lt;` and other escaped characters.  With `XMLWriter`'s `writeRaw` function, I can write `<a>a</a><b>b</b>` and the XML file will include that exact string, not escaped in any way.

Is there a way I can write that string using `SimpleXMLElement` and have it return with the exact string, not escaped.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778865/php-simplexml-addchild-with-another-simplexmlelement) before, but the answer returns an error when I use it and I cannot seem to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - SimpleXML - AddChild with another SimpleXMLElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778865/php-simplexml-addchild-with-another-simplexmlelement)

Comment: Deleting my answer as question is duplicate. You should think of deleting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML doesn't have this ability directly, but it is available in the [DOM](http://php.net/dom) family of functions.  Thankfully, it is easy to work with SimpleXML and DOM at the same time on the same XML document.

The example below uses a *document fragment* to add a couple of elements to a document.

```
<?php

$example = new SimpleXMLElement('<example/>');

// <example/> as a DOMElement
$dom = dom_import_simplexml($example);

// Create a new DOM document fragment and put it inside <example/>
$fragment = $dom->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<a>a</a><b>b</b>');
$dom->appendChild($fragment);

// Back to SimpleXML, it can see our document changes
echo $example->asXML();

?>
```

The above example outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example><a>a</a><b>b</b></example>
```